# How to make background image wider?

Tags: html, css, image, width

I am sorry if the question isn't so good but I really need help.

When I resize my window the image resizes too. I want that. The problem is when it resizes too small the scroll bar at the bottom appears and when I scroll to the right my image is not fit. I need help putting that image in the right place. I don't want to use any

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in the css.

```html
<html><head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Hello World</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css">
            <meta name="google-site-verification" content="hJmWezR-BdO4eF-2HJqeRyPJr01jx1XAucxbiir7eM0">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="extra">
                <header>
                <a href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Hello World" title="Hello World - My first Website.">
                </a>
                </header>
                </div>
                <section>
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav">
                <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><button class="index"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="article"><a href="Articles.html">Articles</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="about"><a href="About.html">About</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="contact"><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="fgame"><a href="fall-game-master/Fallgame.html">Fall Game</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="jgame"><a href="easiest-game-ever-master/easygame.html">Jump Game</a></button></td>
                    <td><button class="meme"><a href="meme.html">Among us Memes</a></button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </div>
                </nav>
                </section>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="para">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is my first webpage. <br>I hope you like it.</p>
        <hr>
        <p>Another paragraph.</p>
<ul>
<li>I made this sentance.</li>
<li>And this one.</li>
<li>Don't forget this one.</li>
<li>Tell me, who do you think made this sentence?</li>
<li>I used HTML coding for this.</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>I made this bold.<strong></strong></strong></p><p><strong><strong>
</strong></strong></p></div><strong><strong>

        <img src="img/smile.bmp" height="10%">
        <br>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<h2>Welcome to Hello World.</h2>
    <hr>
<footer>
<a href="https://www.jw.org/en/"><img src="img/jw.jpg" title="Go to JW.ORG"></a><br>
<hr>
Copyright © HelloWorld 2021-2021
</footer>
    
</strong></strong></body></html>
```

That is my html.

Here is my css and web look.
[image: css and web look 1]

[image: css and web look 2]

Here is a better image of the web look from a mobile.

[image: mobile view]

Comment: please don't use screenshots to add css/ code in your questions. Copy the css into the question instead, using the code format or  stack snippets. Screenshots are very hard to read!

Comment: have you considered using repeat-x or object-fit? Better to fix your nav to be fix your nav to be responsive, but worth experimenting all the same.. it's all learning!

Comment: Ok. How can you do that?

Comment: there are many questions pertaining to responsiveness on the SO site (and other resources too!) .. I'm sure you can find a few questions already on stackoverflow that will address your questions

Comment: I looked and none had to do with their table being longer than their background image

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the background image is not wide enough, it is that your navigation is too wide, wider than the screen width, which causes the horizontal scroll bar. You need to make your navigation and iframe responsive. I would start by removing your nav from the `<table>` (that is not what a table element is for). Here is some very basic html and css to get you started on styling those troublesome elements responsively. You will then need to re-work your background image to make it look how you'd like, maybe by putting your navigation inside of it.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Articles.html">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="fall-game-master/Fallgame.html">Fall Game</a></li>
        <li><a href="easiest-game-ever-master/easygame.html">Jump Game</a></li>
        <li><a href="meme.html">Among us Memes</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 560px;
    margin: auto;
}

.nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav a {
    /* Make whatever color you want */
    color: red;
}

@media(min-width: 650px) {

    .nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Notice the navigation links stack on top of each other on a small screen. You'd need a button and some JavaScript to "open" and "close" the navigation.

Comment: Ok. How would you fix it then?

Comment: I can't code the whole page for you but I updated my answer with some code to get you started and should solve the horizontal scroll bar for now. The aspect ratio of the iframe will become distorted a little when the page resizes. I may come back to update that for you.